# Sample data from combination of two probability distributions

Tags: numpy, statistics, scipy, probability-theory

I want to make a mock catalogue. I have access to two sets of real data and I want to use their properties to generate the mock catalogue:
 The **first** one contains the information from **magnitude** and **redshift** (`z`). 
 The **second** set has information about **magnitude** and **weighted ellipticity** of galaxies.

In my final simulated catalogue I want to generate **redshift** and **weighted ellipticity**. I would like to use the underlying property of **magnitude** versus **redshift** and **magnitude** versus **weighted ellipticity**. However I also have a well-define formula that discribes the distribution of redshift and the functionality is given as following (`GeneralRandom` is a class that is able to generate a random sample follows the given distribution `p(z)`):

```
ng=24000
def p(z):
    z0=1./3.;eta=1.0
    value=eta*(z**2)*np.exp(-1*(z/z0)**eta)/scipy.special.gamma(3./eta)/z0**3 
    return value

catalogue_generate=GeneralRandom(x=np.arange(0.0, 1.5, .001), p_func=p, Nrl=10000)

catalogue_generate.set_pdf(np.arange(0.0, 1.5, .001), catalogue_generate.p_val, 10000)
redshift=catalogue_generate.random( ng)[0]
redshift=random.sample(redshift, ng)
```

I used the defined function for the redshift distribution to sample redshift with above procedure.
Now I am confused how I could combine the `kde` computed from two distribution and estimate  the parameter that I am interested in, e.g.  `weighted ellipticity` for my mock catalogue from the sampled `redshift`? 
The plot is illustrating the **Gaussian KDE** estimated from the two known real data sets. I don't know how I could independently use the output of `stats.gaussian_kde` to just insert the computed `redshift` and obtain the corresponding `magnitude` follows `2D kde` and then from estimated `magnitude` in the previous step, and estimated KDE for `magnitude` and `weight` estimate the `weighted ellipticities` for the input `redshift`?
Is it statistically correct to say the problem looks like this:

[image]

I also don't know computationally, how it should be done?!!

I will appreciate if somebody can describe how I could tackle my problem and a bit of python programming tips or introducing useful libraries.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let R = red shift, M = magnitude, W = weight. If I understand correctly, you are trying to sample from P(W, R).

Given the data at hand, you do not have enough information for a complete solution: note that P(W, R) = P(W | R) P(R) where P(W | R) = \int P(W, M | R) dM = \int P(W | M, R) P(M | R) dM. You can derive P(M | R) from P(M, R) for which you have data, but you do not have data to derive P(W | M, R) -- you only have P(W, M) so you can derive P(W | M) but not P(W | M, R) -- in order to make progress, you must assume that R does not give you any more information about W if you already have M. I don't know anything about your problem domain -- you must study that assumption to say whether it's reasonable or not.

Assuming that P(W | M, R) = P(W | M) is a reasonable assumption, you can proceed by sampling from P(R), then P(M | R), then P(W | M) to get a pair (R, W). For sampling P(M | R) and P(W | M), you will need to sample from a conditional distribution derived from kernel density. I don't have a formula at the moment but I think it is relatively simple. Maybe I'll work on it tomorrow, I don't have time tonight.

Comment: I think assuming `R` won't give me more information about `w`, so it would be relatively fair assumption. But how could I compute conditional distribution? I will appreciate also if you give me some tips whether `stats.gaussian_kde` can produce conditional probability and how could I mix them up inorder to get a sample for W with the given probability of R?

Comment: I found another analytical formula for P(R|M) and another data set which contains both information of `magnitude`, `redshift` and `weighted ellipticity` so the problem now would be like this P(W|R)=\int P(R|M)P(W|R,M)P(M)/P(R)dM which seems more complicated than before, right? and now I don't know how I should combine all the information to sample `redshift` and `weighted ellipticity`?

Comment: @Dalek You say you have a data set containing all three variables. Terrific, if you want to construct a model for P(W | R), just use R and W from the new data set and ignore M.

Comment: but on the other hand, I know there is a relation between `magnitude` and `redshift` and `magnitude` and `weighted ellipticity`,but it is not necessarily mean that a direct relation between `redshift` and `weight` exists. Because for instance in higher magnitude the type of galaxies would change so `P(R|M)` will change on the other hand `magnitude` and `weighted ellipticity` are related since in higher `magnitude` the data is getting more noisy so the `wighted ellipticity` would reduce.

Comment: Well even if I make this assumption then I need to fit a conditional kernel density estimate and from the above analytical formula for `p(z)` draw a sample of `redshift` and then use this conditional probability (I don't know how) to sample `weighted magnitude`, is it the correct approach?

Comment: @Dalek If you sample P(R) and then P(W | R), that is equivalent to sampling from P(W, R). You can construct a new, artificial sample from the existing data via method (2) in my first comment. The marginal distribution P(R) will be the same as the marginal distribution in the sample. If it is important that the marginal distribution be P(R) as given by a formula, you will have to construct P(W | R) and sample from that. So the important question at this point is, how important is it that the marginal distribution P(R) be given by the formula? Is it a requirement or just a suggestion?

Comment: It has been mention in literature as an analytical formula people use to make mock catalogue, I don't know how much necessary is that my simulated data follow the given distribution.

Comment: @Dalek Maybe you can decide whether P(R) matters by considering the purpose of the mock catalogue. For what are you going to use the catalogue? Does it make a difference in the end results if you construct the catalogue by one method or another?

Comment: it is for testing another `MCMC` code that compute the properties of cluster of galaxies like `mass` ans so on ....

Comment: @Dalek Well, given that, it seems like it's OK to generate the mock catalogue via (2) and not use the formula for P(R).

Comment: now I got stuck how to practically first obtain non-parametrically the probability distribution of `wighted ellipticity` and `redshift` and then generate a mock catalogue contain both quantities from the obtained distribution. any suggestion?

Comment: @Dalek use method (2) from my original comment. Namely, select a datum (W, R) at random (with equal probability) and then take that as a Gaussian density with mean equal to (W, R) and some variance (you have to pick a number for the variance). Then take one sample from that bump. (I assume you can figure that out.) That is equivalent to constructing a kernel density estimate and sampling from it.